# Timeout message logging, and retry storm, in infinispan cache after upgrading from Wildfly 20 to 23.0.1

Tags: wildfly, infinispan

We just upgraded from wildfly 20 to 23, and are now seeing issues with infinispan erroring out, and getting into log and retry loops.  The issues happens 100's of times per second after it starts, and only stops when one node of the cluster is turned off.

We get the below error, that retires indefinitely, using about 30Mbs of bandwidth between the servers, when normally it is ~10-30Kbs.  The confusing part of the error, is node 1, it received an error from node 2, and node 2's error is a timeout from node 1.  I have tried moving from the udp to tcp stack, and am still seeing the same issue (it is a 2 node cluster).

I increased the remote timeout from the default of 10 seconds to 30, and almost immediately saw the same error.

Is there a new setting needed in wildfly 23, or some other miss on my side, or am I hitting a new bug?

Here is the jgroups config:

```
                <stack name="udp" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <transport type="UDP" shared="false" socket-binding="jgroups-udp" statistics-enabled="true">
                        <property name="log_discard_msgs">
                            false
                        </property>
                        <property name="port_range">
                            50
                        </property>
                    </transport>
                    <protocol type="PING" module="org.jgroups" statistics-enabled="true"/>
                    <protocol type="MERGE3" module="org.jgroups" statistics-enabled="true"/>
                    <socket-protocol type="FD_SOCK" module="org.jgroups" socket-binding="jgroups-udp-fd" statistics-enabled="true"/>
                    <protocol type="FD_ALL" module="org.jgroups" statistics-enabled="true"/>
                    <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT" module="org.jgroups" statistics-enabled="true"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2" module="org.jgroups" statistics-enabled="true"/>
                    <protocol type="UNICAST3" module="org.jgroups" statistics-enabled="true"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE" module="org.jgroups" statistics-enabled="true"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.GMS" module="org.jgroups" statistics-enabled="true"/>
                    <protocol type="UFC" module="org.jgroups" statistics-enabled="true"/>
                    <protocol type="MFC" module="org.jgroups" statistics-enabled="true"/>
                    <protocol type="FRAG3"/>
                </stack>
```

and infinispan

```
<cache-container name="localsite-cachecontainer" default-cache="epi-localsite-default" statistics-enabled="true">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000" channel="localsite-appCache"/>
<replicated-cache name="bServiceCache" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <locking isolation="NONE"/>
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <expiration lifespan="1800000"/>
                </replicated-cache>
```

```
22:47:52,823 WARN  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-223,application-localsite,node1) ISPN000071: Caught exception when handling command SingleRpcCommand{cacheName='application-bServiceCache', 
command=PutKeyValueCommand{key=SimpleKey [XXXX,2021-05-06,1412.0,75.0,null], value=[YYYY[pp=4 Pay,PaymentDue=2021-05-28], ppAvaliablity[firstPaymentDue=2021-05-28], ppAvaliablity[firstPaymentDue=2021-05-28]], flags=[], commandInvocationId=CommandInvocation:node2:537,
 putIfAbsent=true, valueMatcher=MATCH_ALWAYS, metadata=EmbeddedExpirableMetadata{version=null, lifespan=1800000, maxIdle=-1}, successful=true, topologyId=18}}: org.infinispan.remoting.RemoteException: ISPN000217: Received exception from node2, see cause for remote stack trace
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ResponseCollectors.wrapRemoteException(ResponseCollectors.java:25)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.MapResponseCollector.addException(MapResponseCollector.java:64)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.MapResponseCollector$IgnoreLeavers.addException(MapResponseCollector.java:102)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.ValidResponseCollector.addResponse(ValidResponseCollector.java:29)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.MultiTargetRequest.onResponse(MultiTargetRequest.java:93)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.impl.RequestRepository.addResponse(RequestRepository.java:52)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1402)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processMessage(JGroupsTransport.java:1305)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.access$300(JGroupsTransport.java:131)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport$ChannelCallbacks.up(JGroupsTransport.java:1445)
        at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:784)
        at org.jgroups.fork.ForkProtocolStack.up(ForkProtocolStack.java:135)
        at org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:309)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FORK.up(FORK.java:142)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG3.up(FRAG3.java:165)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:343)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:876)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:243)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.deliverMessage(UNICAST3.java:1049)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.addMessage(UNICAST3.java:772)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.handleDataReceived(UNICAST3.java:753)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:405)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:592)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:132)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FD.up(FD.java:227)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:254)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE3.up(MERGE3.java:281)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:300)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1396)
        at org.jgroups.util.SubmitToThreadPool$SingleMessageHandler.run(SubmitToThreadPool.java:87)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextReferenceExecutor.execute(ContextReferenceExecutor.java:49)
        at org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextualExecutor$1.run(ContextualExecutor.java:70)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 4485 from node1
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor551.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readGenericThrowable(ThrowableExternalizer.java:282)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:259)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ThrowableExternalizer.readObject(ThrowableExternalizer.java:42)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readWithExternalizer(GlobalMarshaller.java:728)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNonNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:709)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:358)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.BytesObjectInput.readObject(BytesObjectInput.java:32)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.responses.ExceptionResponse$Externalizer.readObject(ExceptionResponse.java:49)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.responses.ExceptionResponse$Externalizer.readObject(ExceptionResponse.java:41)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readWithExternalizer(GlobalMarshaller.java:728)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNonNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:709)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.readNullableObject(GlobalMarshaller.java:358)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromObjectInput(GlobalMarshaller.java:192)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.GlobalMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(GlobalMarshaller.java:221)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.processResponse(JGroupsTransport.java:1394)
        ... 28 more
```

Comment: are you using the same Infinispan & JGroups version in both nodes?

Comment: I am.  I have made some progress last night, and noticed that other caches we have that aren't having this problem, have locking-isolation and transactions-mode's other than none.  Having changed these to READ-COMMITTED and BATCH respectively, things seem to be we working better.

Comment: using BATCH will make the cache transactional. Are you able to collect some logs? or make a reproducer?  if possible, open a ticker in JIRA: https://issues.redhat.com/projects/ISPN/issues

Comment: I can definitely collect some logs, are there specific loggers and levels that need to be enabled in order to get the info needed?  A reproducer could be hard, it is a large app, and it has to be running multi-node to reproduce, but happy to gather any info I can.

Comment: enable trace level for class `org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport`. It will be verbose but it will register all messages sent/received.

Comment: @laoseth when migrating from WF20 to WF23, did you used same standalone.xml?  Or you used default from WF23 and changed to your needs?

Comment: @MartinChoma I used an existing one, and tried my best to upgrade it. I had used the upgrade tool here in the past https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-server-migration, but wildfly 23 support was only patched in 2 weeks ago, and I was upgrading before that.  I can try re-running the old standalone through the tool now, and seeing what changes it makes that i missed

Comment: @pruivo I will setup an instance with that logging, and create a ticket in the redhat jira linking to this article when I do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also attach the configuration for your "localsite-appCache" channel?
Can you also attach a code snippet that demonstrates how you reference the cache in your application?